# MVC Kendo UI Grid - call function after all the rows have been expanded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface, kendo-ui, grid

I am using the ASP.NET MVC Kendo grid.
On click of a button, I need to expand all the rows.
Here is the code for the same:

```
var row = $(this).closest("tr.k-master-row");
grid.data("kendoGrid").expandRow(row);
```

Where this and grid have been defined. This works well.

On expand of each row, the following event is called (for each row), as the detail template is bound:
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("onInnerGridDataBound"))

```
function onInnerGridDataBound(e) {
     //Do something here
}
```

My requirement is that after I initiate the call to expand all the rows, I have a few lines in the code, which should be executed only after all the rows have been expanded. So,

```
 function expandAll()
 {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr.k-master-row"); //Step1
    grid.data("kendoGrid").expandRow(row);"); //Step2


    //Do something after the onInnerGridDataBound event is called for
    every expanded row. 
    ..................................
    //Ideally should be step 4 to be executed, but executes immediately
    //after step2
 }

//Ideally Step 3 to execute, but executes last
function onInnerGridDataBound(e) {
     //Do something here
}
```

I want to avoid using the setTimeout method, as I don't know how long it will take or any flags.

Hope to find an answer soon.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

Not sure if it'd work here but it should be something like:

```
$.when(grid.data("kendoGrid").expandRow(row))
 .done(function () {
     //after completing expandRow event
 })
 .then(function() {
    //something else
});
```

Again, this may not work at all since I'm not sure if kendoGrid events can be treated as deferred objects but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Yeah, that did not work. I had tried it earlier. Thanks though!